# How to "Control" the Type of Solutions Mathematica Produces Using the Solve Function

Tags: equation-solving

Given multiple fractions I am using the Solve function to find the values of the variables $x[1],\ldots,x[7]$ such that the numerator and denominator of each fraction are both 0.

I usually have infinitely many solutions. For a given fraction $f$, my approach in Mathematica is as follows.

```
f = x[2] (6 x[4]^2 + 6 x[3] x[6] + g[4] x[5]^2 x[7]^2)/(x[5] x[7]);

eqn = {Numerator[f] == 0, Denominator[f] == 0};

vars = Table[x[i], {i, 1, 7}];

Solve[eqn, vars]
```

Mathematica's output is

```
{{x[2] -> 0, x[5] -> 0}, 
{x[2] -> 0, x[7] -> 0}, 
{x[5] -> 0, x[6] -> -(x[4]^2/x[3])}, 
{x[6] -> -(x[4]^2/x[3]), x[7] -> 0}, 
{x[3] -> 0, x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 0}, 
{x[3] -> 0, x[4] -> 0, x[7] -> 0}}
```

Because of *Solution 3* and *Solution 4* (I will refer to these general solutions), the system has infinitely many solutions.

Given that *Solutions 3, 4* contain fractions, the solutions will be undefined whenever the denominator is equal to zero. For example, *Solution 3* is only valid when $x[3]\neq 0$. (By my understanding) Mathematica looks at the case $x[3]=0$ separately. It can be verified manually that when $x[3]=0$ in *Solution 3*, then we must have $x[4]=0$. So, the solution set $\{x[3]=0,x[4]=0,x[5]=0\}$, which is *Solution 5*, is a specific (by specific I mean that the solution is purely numerical in nature) solution of the (general) *Solution 3*.

Similarly, the general *Solution 4* has the specific solution *Solution 6*.

*Solution 1* and *Solution 2* are independent of the general solutions.

I am not interested in solutions of the type *Solutions 5, 6* and as such with like to get rid (if possible) of these from the solutions generated by Mathematica.

For this particular example, I can manually have a look at Mathematica's output and easily conclude which specific solutions are tagged to general solutions. However, this becomes a problem when the output produced by Mathematica is large. It becomes quite tedious to decide which solutions are of type *Solutions 1, 2* (which I need) and which are of type *Solutions 5, 6* (which I don't need).

Thanks, Radz

Comment: Solution 5 is not a special form of solution 3. Note in particular that it places no restriction on x[6].

Comment: Solution 5 is indeed a "special" form of Solution 3. Manually, if $x[5]=0$ in the denominator than either $x[2]=0$ or $6(x[4]^2+x[3]x[6])=0$ in the numerator. The latter solution can be rearranged to $x[6]=-\frac{x[4]^2}{x[3]}$ provided that $x[3]\neq 0$, which is Solution 3. Letting $x[3]=0$ in $6(x[4]^2+x[3]x[6])=0$ gives $6x[4]^2=0$. So, $x[4]=0$ and $x[6]$ is a free parameter.

Comment: Once again: Solution 3 places x[6] in an algebraic relation to other variables. Solution 5 does not. Ergo, solution 5 cannot be subsumed by solution 3. What you note above is that they arise from different branches of a conditional.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau, Solution 3 is required to get Solution 5. Both are derived from the equation $6(x[4]^2+x[3]x[6])=0$. How are you going to get Solution 5 without using Mathematica?

Comment: (1) You are perhaps using a nonstandard meaning of "special form". (2) My remark really has nothing to do with Mathematica per se. It's about the underlying math. (3) To get a bit technical, one solution is a specialized form of another if its associated prime ideal properly contains that of the other solution. That relation does not exist between solutions 5 and 3.

Comment: I am not interested in the term "special form" (which was coined by you) and its definition. I have not used this term in my post. I am pointing out the fact that one needs to know the form of Solution 3 to get Solution 5.

Comment: You used the phrase that 'Solution 5, is a specific (by specific I mean that the solution is purely numerical in nature) solution of the (general) Solution 3"; that is what I referred to as (not in fact being) a special form. I am simply pointing out that that is not the case, and that you were not clearly stating whatever it is you actually are trying to obtain. A consequence is that you are unlikely to get much guidance. Beyond that, I can only say that this no longer holds any interest for me.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to use `Reduce` instead of `Solve`. With your equation above (but change the `g[4]` to `x[4]`) this gives:

```
Reduce[eqn, vars]

(x[2] == 0 && x[5] == 0) || 
(x[2] == 0 && x[7] == 0) || 
(x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 0 && x[5] == 0) || 
(x[3] == 0 && x[4] == 0 && x[7] == 0) || 
(x[5] == 0 && x[3] != 0 && x[6] == -(x[4]^2/x[3])) || 
(x[3] != 0 && x[6] == -(x[4]^2/x[3]) && x[7] == 0)
```

The advantage of this form is that the fifth and sixth solutions both have the condition `x[3] != 0` explicitly in the answer, so that you can search for such answers programmatically.

Comment: Dear bill s, Thanks. Actually, I am interested in the 5th and 6th solutions, where $x[3]\neq 0$. I am not interested in the 3rd and 4th solutions (where $x[3]=0$) because I can get these by looking at the 5th and 6th solutions.